# Ready to use Red5 application

Tags: video-streaming, red5

I'm looking for an existing Red5 application.

Our need is pretty basic:
* Only one feed is needed
* Restrict broadcasting by IP address or user/pass
* Restrict viewing by user/pass or token

I found [videowhisper](http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=RTMP+Applications), but it seem to lack authentication features.

An open source app would be great, but I can accept a commercial product if the cost is not too high.

The RTMPT solution seem good for restricting viewing access, but anybody can still start to broadcast at my server without authorization.  How can I limit broadcasting access?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following IP security mechanism using RTMPT (RTMP over HTTP):

All RTMPT request are passed to red5 (port 5080) by using mod_proxy in my apache config, except for the /open/1 requests:

```
#send open/1 request to authentification script:
Alias /open/1 /var/www/html/auth.php

#other RTMP request directly to red5:
ProxyPass /send http://localhost:5080/send
ProxyPassReverse /send http://localhost:5080/send
ProxyPass /idle http://localhost:5080/idle
ProxyPassReverse /idle http://localhost:5080/idle
ProxyPass /close http://localhost:5080/close
ProxyPassReverse /close http://localhost:5080/close
ProxyPass /fcs http://localhost:5080/fcs
ProxyPassReverse /fcs http://localhost:5080/fcs
```

When a user starts the player, the web page will first contact a php script to verify the user is logged in. If so, its IP-address will be temporarily stored including the current time (timestamp). Then the RTMPT stream will be started on port 80. Now the auth.php script will receive the /open/1 request from the player. It will check the IP-address and timestamp. If the IP-address is present and the timestamp is not older then about 3 seconds, the /open/1 request is passed to red5. The result (the identifier) is passed back to the player. In PHP:

```
<?php
 //after user is verified, send /open/1 request to red5:
 $data = `curl -s -F a=b localhost:5080/open/1`;
 $data_size = strlen($data);

 header("Content-Type: application/x-fcs");
 header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
 header("Content-Length: $data_size");
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

 echo $data;  //return answer from red5 (identifier) back to player
 exit;
?>
```

Unfortunately, the /open/1 request does not contain any cookies or referer info from the web page, only the REMOTE_ADDR (IP-address) and REQUEST_TIME from the client is useful info from  PHP $_SERVER variable (using JW-player).

Comment: Interesting... I get a 404 at POST /fcs/ident2 (but I can access that url on the :5080 port with my browser).  My stream is then stalled at requests POST /idle/xx/xxxx with http status 400 (bad request).  Any idea?

Comment: Mmm, the post idle return http 200 for some seconds and then http 400.  Video is never played.

Comment: 404 is correct for /fcs/indent2, see the [RTMPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol#HTTP_Tunneling_.28RTMPT.29)  protocol. Then the server expects the /open/1 request. Looks like your PHP script is not working as expected because the /idle requests are not answered. Please try first without the PHP script by adding the /open/1 to the ProxyPass. If this is working, test the PHP script. Simple write $data into a file e.g.:  file_put_contents('log.txt',"data: $data \n",FILE_APPEND); The log file should show identifier(s) returned by red5.

Comment: Or run the auth.php directly from the command line: php auth.php. It should show you the returned id, about 13 characters. Be sure the PHP script has exec rights (0755).

Comment: The auth.php script seem to work, but the ID is not 13 characters long.  It's an integer.  I got "6" as id the first time, then "8" after a second run.

Comment: I found things that talk about the 8088 port after some search.  Is it needed?  My red5 setup is not using that port.

Comment: Full log:
    "POST /fcs/ident2 HTTP/1.1" 404 204
    "POST /open/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 218
    "POST /idle/12/0 HTTP/1.1" 200 216
    "POST /send/12/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 3292
    "POST /send/12/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 407
    "POST /send/12/3 HTTP/1.1" 200 248
    "POST /send/12/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 216
    "POST /send/12/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 528
    "POST /idle/12/6 HTTP/1.1" 200 216
    "POST /idle/12/7 HTTP/1.1" 200 216
    "POST /idle/12/8 HTTP/1.1" 200 216
(POST /idle continue after...)

Comment: I started working with Red5 when 1.0.0 was still not released. I worked with RC2 and rtmpt was not working in RC2. This work now!  But I have a problem, how can I block someone to stream using the RTMPT protocol? They have to be able to just watch, they are not allowed to stream.